# On notification button click intent starting new activity instead of resuming

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-mediaplayer, android-notifications

I am trying to implement a custom notification for my mediaplayer with notification bar that has just one button that will act as stop and play control.

So far have implemented  the notification successfully and the button is making the function call, but the problem is that onReceive when I create an intent and call the activity, the activity gets **recreated** on top of the old one and I get bad double echoing media player playing in the background.

Have tried to make the launchMode= Single, but when I make it single the button click makes no difference, it means that the function call is not getting made if I turn the launch mode to **SINGLE** instead of **STANDARD**.

MAIN_ACTIVITY CODE SNIPPET

```
//NOTIFICATION RELATED CLASSES
    private NotificationCompat.Builder builder;
    private NotificationManager notificationManager;
    //private int notification_id;
    private RemoteViews remoteViews;
    Context context;
    Intent notification_intent;

    final int notification_id =545816666;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        boolean attachMedia = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("attachMedia",false);
        if (attachMedia) {
            attachMediaActivity();
        }

        //CODE DE NOTIFICATION
        context =this;

        notification_intent=new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);

        notificationManager=(NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        remoteViews=new RemoteViews(getPackageName(),R.layout.custom_notification);

        remoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.notif_icon,R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.notif_title,"BOOM");
        remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.button,"Button");
 Intent button_intent= new Intent("player_control_clicked");
        button_intent.putExtra("id",notification_id);

        PendingIntent p_button_intent=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,123,button_intent,0);
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button,p_button_intent);


        tview=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.playerText);
        btn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.playerButton);

        if(!mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
        {
            tview.setText("Press play");
            btn.setText("Play");
        }
        else
        {
            tview.setText("Playing");
            btn.setText("Stop");
        }

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //Intent notification_intent=new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);

                //THIS CODE UPDATES OLD NOTIFICATION
                PendingIntent pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getActivity(context,0,notification_intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

                builder =new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);

                builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                        .setCustomBigContentView(remoteViews)
                        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                        .setOngoing(true);

                notificationManager.notify(notification_id,builder.build());


               if(!mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
               {
                   //tview.setText("Playing");
                   btn.setText("Stop");
                   playStream();
               }
                else
                {
                    tview.setText("Stopped");
                    btn.setText("Play");
                    mediaPlayer.stop();
                    mediaPlayer.reset();
                }
            }
        });

    }

    public void attachMediaActivity()
    {
        //CODE DE NOTIFICATION
        context =this;

        notification_intent=new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);

        notificationManager=(NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        remoteViews=new RemoteViews(getPackageName(),R.layout.custom_notification);

        remoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.notif_icon,R.drawable.stream_icon);
        remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.notif_title,"Stopped");
        remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.button,"STOPA");

        Intent button_intent= new Intent("player_control_clicked");
        button_intent.putExtra("id",notification_id);

        /*PendingIntent p_button_intent=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,123,button_intent,0);
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button,p_button_intent);*/
        PendingIntent pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getActivity(context,0,notification_intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        builder =new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);

        builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setCustomBigContentView(remoteViews)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setOngoing(true);

        notificationManager.notify(notification_id,builder.build());


        if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
        {
            mediaPlayer.stop();
        }
        else
        {
            playStream();
        }
    }
```

THE BROADCAST LISTENER FOR THE NOTIFICATION BUTTON CLICK THAT CALLS THE ACTIVTY VIA INTENT

```
public class Button_listener extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        manager.cancel(intent.getExtras().getInt("id"));
        Toast.makeText(context, "GENERATED BY NOTIFICATION", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        intent= new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        //intents.addExtra("attachMedia",true); // Extra info
        intent.putExtra("attachMedia",true);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

MY MANIFEST

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:launchMode="singleTop"
    android:noHistory="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>

<receiver android:name="Button_listener">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="player_control_clicked"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Thanks in advance
PS: TRIED EVERY POSSIBLE ANSWER ON STACK

Comment: Have you tried removing `android:noHistory="true"` for the `Activity`?

Comment: Does the issue arise when your app is on foreground and played from notification or when you have closed it by pressing back button and then played from notification?

Comment: @VyshnavRamesh yes exactly .. I just found a work around, instead of relying on the activity i am now relying on the background service and now my notification is completely independent of the Main UI

Comment: Glad you have found the solution

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies within your intent Flag

you have added the flag `intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);`,
change that to `intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);`

For more reference read this https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

Comment: This won't work anymore in new APIs: "Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?"

Comment: Hi, it was not my intention to correct you, I would simply like to leave that clarification to the people who read this answer from now on. Best regards.